Weird summation result computing the expectation of Poisson random variable
Can you explain the obtained difference between these two rapidly convergent infinite sums? The correct answer is $-1/2$, and this should be obtained in both presented cases.

Exp[-1/2] Sum[(1/2)^(k + 1)/Factorial[k + 1] k, {k, -1, ∞}]
(* -(1/Sqrt[E]) *)
Exp[-1/2] Sum[(1/2)^k/Factorial[k] (k - 1), {k, 0, ∞}]
(* -(1/2) *)


I get the same results as you both in v12.3 and in 14.0, and this is indeed weird. Also, none of the other methods seem to work ... I believe you should report this.

Expectation works as expected, i.e., Expectation[k - 1, k \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[1/2]] evaluates to -1/2 Likewise, Mean[TransformedDistribution[k - 1, k \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[1/2]]]

Also strange, if you define the partial sum:
$$ $$
partial =   Exp[-1/2]  Sum[(1/2)^(k + 1)/Factorial[k + 1]  k, {k, -1, kMax}]
$$ $$
And then take the DiscreteLimit as you got to infinity you get the correct answer:
$$ $$
DiscreteLimit[partial, kMax -> Infinity]
$$ $$
(*-1/2*)
Maybe Mathematica is using some infinite sum identity incorrectly?

I would report this to "support@wolfram.com"

I reported the problem. Got the confirmation that they see this error too and working to fix it.
